# Ensure jQuery fadeIn is always to 100% visibility, timer is upsetting it

Tags: jquery, fadein

I have some elements which are used as tool tips. These are faded in with jQuery on mouseover/click of elements with the appropriate controlling class. Any element which has been faded in should fade out again after 5 seconds.

This is pretty simple with jQuery, but if I mouseover one controller, and then another within 5 seconds, the timer is not reset, so say there's been a 2 second break between displaying one tip and the secopnd, the second will fadeOut after 3 seconds.

So, Googling, and using this site, resulted in this

```
function showTips(triggerElement, tipText) { 
    $('#tipText').html(tipText);        
    clearTimeout($('#tipNote').stop().data('timer')); // clears timeOut to fade tooltip away
    $('#tipNote').fadeIn(function () { // fadeIn tooltip and sets a timeout function to hide it again
        $.data(this, 'timer', setTimeout(function () { $('#tipNote').fadeOut(); }, '5000'));
    });
};
```

There are two problems here

1) if you mouse over a second controller element whilst the first tooltip is not fully faded in, (ie has an opacity of 50% for example at that moment), the next tooltip seems to only fade in to the final opacity that the first one reached (ie 50%), it stores that opacity in memory for some reason.

2) I don't completely understand the code as it came from an example on here, I'm not sure what .data does, or indeed the $.data call in the final line. Since I don't completely understand it I am not sure how to correct the fadeIn issue.

==== edit ===

adding in my HTML

The tooltip container is a single div whose content is populated by the controller element, ie:

Controller element:

```
<span id='marginAlertTotal' class='hoverTip' title='this is the tooltip content'></span>
```

This has a class of hoverTip so works on hover

My actual toolip is:

```
    <div class='tooltipContent borderRad5 tooltip-right tooltip' id='tipNote'>
        <span class="tiptext" id="tipText"></span>
        <div class='tooltip-pointer-down ui-widget-content'>
            <div class='tooltip-pointer-down-inner'></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Then from my Javascript function above (called by click or hover) the content of #tipText is populated by the title attribute of the controller.

Answer (score 0):

It can also be done like this:
make a div containing 2 controls, 1 for the hover, and 1 with the div that should show on hover. if you do it correctly the div that should show will be the next one after the control you hover. give all tooltips the same class but unique id's

```
$('.myControls').mouseenter(function(){
   $('.yourTooltipClass').each(function(){
      $(this).fadeout(200); //or just $(this).hide(); to hide it immediatly
   });
$(this).next().fadein(time in ms).delay(5000).fadeout(time in ms);
});
```

This will check all your tooltips and hide them all.
Then it will show the correct tooltip and hide it after 5 seconds.
To be honest im a bit short on time so its not the best solution because it will also hide the tooltip after 5 seconds if you keep your mouse on the control.

But I think that should work.

Comment: Ah, I think I might not have posted clearly what I am doing with the HTML. The div that contains the actual tooltip content is the same div regardless of which tool tip controller is clicked/hovered, the content being filled by the "title" attribute of the control element. I am trying to keep my HTML down by using the same container but populating it with different content and positioning with jquery.offset. All that works, but the fading in to the wrong opacity is annoying! - original post edited to show HTML